# Variable range string hashing function for odd/prime buckets

Tags: java, hash

Does anyone know a hashing function (for Strings, if it matters) for a variable range of buckets, which is always odd (or prime, if necessary)?

Essentially, I'm looking for a hashing function which will provide a uniform distribution over n buckets, where n is odd (or prime, since n will be small).

Java's `.hashCode()` provides uniform distribution, but only for powers of 2.

Here is [some quick test code I whipped up which asserts this](https://gist.github.com/4698738).

I cross-posted this on the [CS Theory StackExchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16330/variable-range-string-hashing-function-for-odd-prime-buckets) since it seems to fall somewhere between theory & engineering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your program with 37 as buckets length, and the hashing part replaced with

```
for (String key : keys) {
    int hash = key.hashCode();
    int index = Math.abs(hash % buckets.length);
    buckets[index] = buckets[index] + 1;
}
```

leads to the following result:

```
Bucket 0: 4152
Bucket 1: 2593
Bucket 2: 2703
Bucket 3: 2620
Bucket 4: 2742
Bucket 5: 2647
Bucket 6: 2707
Bucket 7: 2673
Bucket 8: 2664
Bucket 9: 2685
Bucket 10: 2734
Bucket 11: 2708
Bucket 12: 2661
Bucket 13: 2678
Bucket 14: 2681
Bucket 15: 2662
Bucket 16: 2682
Bucket 17: 2667
Bucket 18: 2619
Bucket 19: 2572
Bucket 20: 2608
Bucket 21: 2669
Bucket 22: 2670
Bucket 23: 2629
Bucket 24: 2748
Bucket 25: 2651
Bucket 26: 2618
Bucket 27: 2628
Bucket 28: 2740
Bucket 29: 2608
Bucket 30: 2650
Bucket 31: 2645
Bucket 32: 2687
Bucket 33: 2699
Bucket 34: 2627
Bucket 35: 2715
Bucket 36: 2558
Mean: 2702.7027027027025
Standard Deviation: 245.8085241264752
```

which looks quite good.

You're not testing the distribution of `String.hashCode()`. You're testing the distribution if HashMap's `hash()` method, which uses the key's hashCode, and has been designed to try getting a uniform distribution for its capacity, which MUST be a power of 2. If `hashCode()` already returns well-distributed values, simply taking the modulo using a prime number as divisor will lead to a good distribution.

Comment: Agh, brilliant. I originally did not have the extra hash() fiddling, was getting the same results. I knew I had to mod it but kept getting negative indices.. didn't even occur to me to use `Math.abs()`. Thanks so very much.